# State of the Union

Tags: wordplay

A topical puzzle for you all.

Can you tell me, briefly, which of the following US states is the odd one out, and why?

- California
- Colorado
- Connecticut
- Delaware
- Hawaii
- Illinois
- Oregon
- Rhode Island

> Hint: The ones remaining after the odd one out have a common, topical property that is not shared by any of the other 43 states.

Comment: Hint: The wording of the puzzle is significant.

Comment: Man, why the downvotes?  I listed a bunch of answers in the vein of "too broad" just for fun, but I knew they were highly unlikely until I got the right one.  OP hinted from the get-go that it was *topical* and that you had to be *brief*, both key elements of the proper answer which made it not at all too broad.

Comment: Does this question require one to know voting statistics?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the correct answer has been given already, but has not yet been accepted.  Paging @paolo to the Puzzing SE lounge ...

Answer (score 8):

Take your pick.

> Rhode Island - it's the only one whose name isn't one word.
>  Hawaii - it's the only one that's actually an island.
>  Delaware - it's the only one with fewer than 4 electoral votes
>  Colorado - it's the only one with all non-natural borders
>  Connecticut - it's the only one whose abbreviation contains no vowel
>  Connecticut again - it's the only one whose name is an odd length *
>     <sup>**requires you include the space in Rhode Island in its length*</sup>
>  **Delaware - it's the only one whose abbreviation's letters are not found in "Hillary Clinton"**

These are fun.  I can go all day. :)

Comment: Note the puzzle tag and the wording of the question.

Comment: The answer in your latest edit is getting closer, but it's not topical.

Comment: Bingo! You got there.

Comment: That took a bit of thinking. And got there before the hint, yay me!  :)  fun one!

Comment: @paolo If this is the right answer you should green-check Accept it, so people don't keep trying new answers

Answer (score 1):

> Connecticut

because it is the only one with

> an odd number of characters in its name.

Comment: That was already said in my answer. Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery? :)

Comment: @Rubio I honestly didn't see it there.  I opened the spoiler, saw a wall of text, and thought "That's too much writing to be this answer".

Answer (score 0):

> Colorado

because

> It's the only state where Hillary received less than 50% of the vote.

Comment: That's related, but it's not "brief" enough.